# Simple AndroidApp to open a web link is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, implicit

I was watching a tutorial video on android development where they were teaching about implicit intents. Its a simple app really, it explains how implicit intent works by opening an URL through the app. Anyways, I follow all of the steps, I even make a toast to see if the edit text view was receiving the url string or not and came up with this:

```
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        url = view.findViewById(R.id.url);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String urlText = url.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), urlText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Implicit Intent to open a web page
                Uri webpage = Uri.parse(urlText);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

When I do press the button (hoping it would ask which app to open the link from) it just shows the toast...

I know there might be a silly mistake here but I just can't see it please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 11 and above there are limitation to querying other packages. See https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Because of that your `intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager())` fails and the `startActivity()` is not executed.

I would just delete the `if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)` altogether and just call `startActivity()` without any checks. In case there is no app to handle your Intent, `ActivityNotFoundException` gets thrown. You can add a try-catch for that.

Comment: the app just crashes when I do that

Comment: Examine the stacktrace in logcat to learn the reason for the crash.

Comment: the error goes as:

`2022-04-18 00:49:59.663 6097-6097/com.example.implicitintent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.implicitintent, PID: 6097
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.google.com }`

Comment: `www.google.com` is not a valid URL. Add e.g. `https://` prefix to complete it.

Comment: that solved it thank you so much